# Knowing what sheet a value came from in Excel or Open Office

Tags: excel, vba, openoffice-calc

My first post on SO concerns an excel project. Technically I'm using Open Office, but I figure it's more or less the same. If it can't be done in OO, I can use Excel too. Here's my situation:

I've got quite a few sheets, with a value in each, that changes depending on the other values in the sheet. I've also got a "Result" page that references the value from each sheet and displays the lowest value with a MIN function. I've been looking for a way to determine which sheet that value came from.

Something along the lines of:

> "The lowest value is: *=MIN('Sheet1'.F9; 'Sheet2'.F9; 'Sheet3'.F9)* The value came from *Referenced sheet*"

With the non-italicised text being in their own cells of course.
I'm not too hot with vba so if this could be done with the standard functions that would be great, but I'm willing to learn some basic vba (if only to understand what I'm doing) to make this work.

Comment: I can't answer your actual question but you might save yourself some long formulas by defining some 3-d named ranges: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-HP010102346.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very low-key way of doing it. Using only three sheets, this seems suitable though.

In cells A1-C1,

- `Sheet1` contains `1 2 3`;
- `Sheet2` contains `5 1 6`; and
- `Sheet3` contains `8 2 1`.

`Sheet4` then contains:

[image]

where A1-C1 contains the regular `=MIN(Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1)`...

Comment: Ah yes you could do that, true. Though as my example above was only an example and in reality I'm using around around 15 sheets, so it's a bit messy, but doable I suppose. Thanks.